# Setting all select box values to particular value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to set all select boxes to a particular value. Here’s the HTML:

```
<select>
     <option value="-1"
     <option value="55">ENABLE</option>
     <option value="56">DISABLE</option>
     <option value="57">HIDDEN</option>
</select>
```

There are eight such identical select boxes on the page.

What I want to do is, on a particular check box change, I need to set the values of all the select boxes to 55.

I have tried

```
$("input[type='select']").val('55');
```

and

```
$("input[type='select']").attr('selected','55');
```

But neither of them works. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your selectors you are trying to find an `<input>` tag with `type="select"` which is something that is not defined. Input tags could be of type text, radio, checkbox, submit, image, ... What you have in the DOM is a `<select>` tag, so in order to set the value to 55 on all select elements in your page you could simply:

```
$('select').val('55');
```